# Question about adjoint orbits

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a proof or a reference of the following claim:

> Let $G$ be a real connected semi-simple Lie group and let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ be the Cartan decomposition for its Lie algebra. Let $M$ be a closed adjoint orbit in $\mathfrak{g} $. Then there exists a unique $(\beta_0, \beta_1) \in \mathfrak{k} \times \mathfrak{p}$ with $[\beta_0,\beta_1]=0$ such that $M= G. (\beta_0+\beta_1).$

2. Does a similar property also hold for an orbit $M$ in the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group which is endowed with an involution $\theta$, namely does there exists a unique  $(\beta_0, \beta_1) \in \mathfrak{g}^\theta \times \mathfrak{g}^{-\theta}$ such that $M= G.(\beta_0+ \beta_1)$ ? ( $\mathfrak{g}^{\theta}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{-\theta}$ are the subspaces fixed by  the induced involution on $\mathfrak{g}$ and its opposite respectively ) .

Comment: What is the property you want for a compact Lie group $G$?  In that context, $\mathfrak k = \mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak p = \{0\}$, so the decomposition is easy.  (Also, in that context, every orbit is the continuous image of $G$, hence compact, hence closed in $\mathfrak g$.)

Comment: @LSpice,  thanks for your comment! I think your comment is addressed to my question before the edit isn't it ?, I've edited it 1 hour ago because I realize that I forgot  to mention some details.

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418225/question-about-adjoint-orbits#comment1073616_418225).  Still 'closed' is redundant for an orbit of a compact group, but of course there is no harm in stating it anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'll fix that.

Comment: I believe the following implies what you need: for any finite order automorphism $\theta$ of a semisimple Lie algebra one can find a Cartan subalgebra that meets generically each of the eigenspaces of $\theta$ (this follows from Vinberg's theory of theta-groups)

Comment: I [agree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418225/question-about-adjoint-orbits#comment1073755_418225) with @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that this must be a question about $\theta$-groups (I was just coming here to mention [Kostant and Rallis - Orbits and representations associated to symmetric spaces](https://doi.org/10.2307/2373470)), but the papers that I know seem mainly to talk about $K$-orbits on $\mathfrak p$.  @‍მამუკაჯიბლაძე, do you have a reference for your result?  (Probably it's in the Kostant–Rallis paper, or in one of Vinberg's; I don't know them well.)

Comment: @LSpice In this generality - Vinberg, "[Weyl group of a graded Lie algebra](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/IM1976v010n03ABEH001711)" (paywall, sorry). He has detailed analysis of closed orbits, notably the notion of Cartan subspace in an eigenspace of a finite order automorphism, and many other goodies. I don't see all the details though, that's why I am commenting rather than answering.